# How to store logic data without eval()?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eval

I'm working on an app that allows an administrator to set conditions for their shop to offer a special. For example:

```
if (($cartTotal > 200) && (has_item_in_cart($item))) { // free shipping, % discount, etc }
```

They will have a GUI in order to set the conditions, I'm wondering how to store the information. The only solution I've come up with so far is generating an `if` statement and storing it as text in a database and later using `eval()` to evaluate it. I'm incredibly hesitant to use `eval()` in a publicly-available app, though. Are there any alternatives?

It will be utilizing Laravel, if there's any packages that may be available.

Comment: you need to create your own parser, don't ever use eval!

Comment: `eval()` is only dangerous when evaluating strings that were provided by unknown or incompetent parties.

Comment: You'll need to concretize the expression schemes you want to evaluate. If it's really just simple ANDing/ORing and a few predefined function calls, a simple tree and looping over it does the job. -- Also `eval` is perfectly apt when the incoming code is adminstrator defined. It's a good advise to noobs to eschew `eval`. Anyone more proficient will realize that it's the one feature that separates scripting from compiled languages. Ruling it out due to memes isn't clever. (Btw, `eval` and `include` are the same thing.)

Comment: eval still has major drawbacks, even when you can guarantee the expression values, not least if there is an error in the evaluated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like Symfony's Expression Language: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/introduction.html#usage

It'll be much more secure than eval at least! :)

Comment: I am going to give it a shot! :)